# com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse limit when parsing JSON and specifying projection

Tags: java, json, mongodb, parsing, mongo-java

I'm using `com.mongodb.util.JSON` and `parse` method to query a **mongodb** database.

I'm facing an issue in a specific query where I want to choose specific fields to display.

The **mongoshell** query :

`{{type:'exam'},{score:1,_id:0}}`

In Java :

```
String query="{{type:'exam'},{score:1,_id:0}}";
DBObject dbObject=(DBObject) JSON.parse(query);
List<DBObject> dbOList=coll.find(dbObject).toArray();
```

The query should display only `score` field.

This return an empty **dbOList**.

I think that `JSON.parse` can't **parse** query that specify fields to display. Is that true ?

How can I **parse** thie kind of query ?

The application I'm developping is 100% dynamic, users can set queries they want, and I need to handle all possible cases !

I don't have a map, this is why I'm not using **JONGO**.

The **JSON** I want to parse can be more complex than this one given as an example, `JSON.parse` is perfect to parse **nested** **JSON**. But, I also need to handle specific fiedls query.

Am I missing something using `JSON.parse` from `mongo-java-driver v2.12.2`?

**EDITS** :

```
{"_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "exam", "score" : 54.6535436362647 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb578" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 31.95004496742112 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb579" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "homework", "score" : 14.8504576811645 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57a" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "homework", "score" : 63.98402553675503 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57b" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "exam", "score" : 74.20010837299897 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57c" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 96.76851542258362 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57d" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 21.33260810416115 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57e" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 44.31667452616328 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57f" }, "student_id" : 2, "type" : "exam", "score" : 19.88180838833524 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb580" }, "student_id" : 2, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 1.528220212203968 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb581" }, "student_id" : 2, "type" : "homework", "score" : 60.9750047106029 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb582" }, "student_id" : 2, "type" : "homework", "score" : 97.75889721343528 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb583" }, "student_id" : 3, "type" : "exam", "score" : 92.6244233936537 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb584" }, "student_id" : 3, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 82.59760859306996 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb585" }, "student_id" : 3, "type" : "homework", "score" : 50.81577033538815 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb586" }, "student_id" : 3, "type" : "homework", "score" : 92.71871597581605 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb587" }, "student_id" : 4, "type" : "exam", "score" : 87.89071881934647 }
```

The **mongoshell** query I'm trying to use in **JAVA** :

`db.grade.find({type:exam},{score:1,_id:0})`

This query display in the shell only `score` field as I want.

The problem is when I do it in **JAVA** using `JSON.parse`.

Ismail

Comment: Are you sure, that your JSON is valid?

Comment: In a valid JSON file everything must be wrapped in quotes. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev this JSON is valid and workd in mongoshell.

Comment: @morkro quotes aren't the problem when exceuting the query in `JAVA`

Comment: The JSON is invalid. There are two objects which are neither values of a key, nor elements of an array. See http://json.org/ for details about the JSON standard.

Comment: @Philipp The JSON is valid, it allows me to specify fields I want to display.It works in mongoshell , I need to make it work with JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please understand how the mongo query works,

As of mongodb is concerned, The query pattern and projection pattern are in this way,

```
collection.find(query,projection); --> grade.find({type:exam,_id:0},{score:1});
```

So It it obvious that, you need to separate query and projection part. So Give in the following way to execute your query as expected,

```
    String json = "{'type':'exam','student_id':0}";
    DBObject dbObj = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
    DBObject projection = (DBObject) JSON.parse("{'score':1,}");
    System.out.println(dbObj);
    Dao dao = new Dao();
    final DBCollection collection = dao.getDb("test").getCollection("test");
    **List<DBObject> dbOList=collection.find(dbObj,projection).toArray();**
    System.out.println(dbOList);
```

This gives you the result as expected, So for sure you need to seperate the query and projection part as above.

you will get the result as list of score field alone (with ID as default)

```
[{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "53d8574e26b7d8cafbf80f9b"} , "score" : 54.6535436362647}]
```

Thanks and Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try something like this

```
String json = "{'type':'exam','score':1,'_id':0}";
DBObject dbObj = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
```

It properly ends up in the result as you expect,

```
{ "type" : "exam" , "score" : 1 , "_id" : 0}
```

The Reason is obviously, it cannot parse the String, It can parse only JSON.

As we see both your idea and this ends up in the same query framing

Comment: Writing the JSON as u did didn't solved my issue. I still have an empty `List<DBObject>` when I  do a `find`.

Comment: The query is not about displaying all `exam`'s with `score` 1 and `_id` 0. This is about displaying only `score` field.

Comment: Ismail, I know its a sample json, So give me your sample db data and send us the query you framed. And by the tell us what you expect from the db data.

Comment: Could you please see the **Edits**.